# Sharing a printer between two vlans

Tags: vlan, network-printer

I have a Netgear switch which supports VLANs. I want to separate two networks, each one having its own internet gateway and servers, but I want all users from the two VLANs to be able to access the same ethernet printer.

Having never configured a VLAN, what are the steps to configure these so that the networks are separated (ie no access between them) and that they can acces the same printer ?

If someone who has already used a Netgear switch could help me with the specific steps, that would be really great.

Many thanks

Comment: Do they share the same router at the edge?

Comment: doh, ok so you don't have any gear yet besides the one Netgear switch?

Comment: Could a cisco 1600 do this ? I have one with 2x 10mbit/s Ethernet.

Comment: 10Mb is going to be slow.  What kind of a budget do you have?

Comment: Virtually no budget :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys, many thanks for your help.
I have found a more practical solution. I have attached an ethernet print server to one of the printer's usb ports and connected the ethernet to the other VLAN.

This gives the printer dual ethernet ability :)

Never thought I could use the ethernet port and the usb port simultaneously.

Answer (score 11):

Put the printer on a third VLAN and ensure that both user VLANs have access to it via the router.

Comment: This method allows you to keep vlan 1 and 2 separate while still granting access to your printer.  A fairly simple method that’s easy to implement and manage.  Good idea.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have only got a Cisco 1600. But my solution works. Many thanks.

Comment: You might be able to do a router-on-a-stick configuration.

Answer (score 1):

HP LaserJet 4100 Series Printers can have two EIO-format ethernet ports, this would work but you may find adding some basic routing and/or firewalling into your network would be cheaper/easier.

Comment: This printer unfortunately has only one ethernet adapter with a single port on it.

Comment: Right, you said 'a printer', not 'an existing single port printer', this site's for pro sysadmins who list the kit they're asking about unless the make/model isn't chosen yet - I doubt VERY much indeed that this existing printer support VLAN trunking, which is the only way of doing this without routing in place.

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't support VLAN trunking.